# Spam coming from domain, but from a user that I don't have

Tags: email, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop people from using my domain to send spam?](https://serverfault.com/questions/415533/how-to-stop-people-from-using-my-domain-to-send-spam)

I have google apps handling the email for my domain (musikpitch.com).  Some Cialis spam got sent with the email address stacee953-camp@musikpitch.com, but I don't' have that user set up.  What might be happening?

> Begin forwarded message:
>
> From: <> Date: November 4, 2011 7:01:48 AM
>   CDT To:  Subject:
>   =?utf-8?B?QXV0b05vdGlmeTogQ2lhYWxpcyBpcyBhIHNvbHV0aW9uIGZvciBtZW4gd 2l0aCAxbXBvMA==?=
>
> The Following Message was blocked by Surf Control. Message
>   [oa806c7383d49438885c572e1d1c8bcce.pro] triggered rule [Illegal MIME
>   format] at 7:01:48 AM 11/4/2011
>
> Sender: stacee953-camp@musikpitch.com Recipient(s):
>   <> Subject: Ciaalis is a solution for men with
>   1mpo0
>
> Because the message is probably SPAM.  If you believe  this message
>   was blocked in error, please send a  message to POSTMASTER@JBHUNT.COM.
>   Messages returned  to <> will be DISCARDED.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing special. Someone forged the sender of the Spam mail and the recipient bounces this message back to you. But you probably never send the mail. Without the headers of the forwarded mail it is impossible to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks.  If thats the case, are there any steps to take?

Comment: @JoshCrews No. If (and only if) this is a bounce for a forged(!) mail there is nothing you can do. This is called [Backscatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_%28e-mail%29) and can be ignored. Only Google (as your provider) could act.

Comment: @JoshCrews Look into setting up SPF records. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Comment: ^^ But does google entertain SPF?? I guess not !

Comment: Google Apps works very well with SPF - when you signed up they provided you with basic documentation and the recommendation to set up SPF. GMail now uses SPF on all mail, and they're now using (and pushing) Domain Keys in addition to SPF.