# Somebody has been sending spam from my domain. Other than setting SPF records, is there anything else I can do?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, domain, spf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spam coming from domain, but from a user that I don’t have](https://serverfault.com/questions/327815/spam-coming-from-domain-but-from-a-user-that-i-dont-have)
>   [How to stop people from using my domain to send spam?](https://serverfault.com/questions/415533/how-to-stop-people-from-using-my-domain-to-send-spam)

For weeks I've been getting 10-20 delivery failure notices a day. Somebody has chosen one of my domain names to sell Viagra. I immediately checked to make sure I had my SPF records in place, and they were there not - so I added them. Doesn't seem to have slowed anything down, though.

It sucks because at this point, since my addresses have "sent" so many, I'm receiving one spam email every 45 seconds, 24/7.

Is there any other option I may have?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yea, I knew there was a more detailed one around there somewhere ;)

Comment: @BrentPabst Sort by votes :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yea, we're not all SF wunderkind like you! ;)

Comment: What did you put in your SPF records?  In particular, what's the very last bit?  If you use `?all` or `~all` you probably won't stop anything.  `-all` will cause non-valid mails to actually be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you've already setup the SPF record and the spammers have used your domain, it is very likely that you'll be receiving failed delivery notifications for a while now.

I would recommend to setup a spam filter rule to discard the the messages that has anything related to content of spam emails sent using your domain name.